# Is there anyway I can prefix over 1000 lines of CSS at once?

Tags: css, sublimetext, lines, prefix

I have some h1, h2, h3 and a lot of bootstrap snippets that I want to apply only to a specific part of my site, I added a unique class, say .unique but it would take hours to prefix over 1000 of CSS lines

I use sublime text

Thanks in advance

Comment: not really sublime for you. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CSS-preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (there are more). Both can do what you want, by just doing this:

```
.unique {
    // Old CSS goes here
}
```

The have many other advantages over normal CSS.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

common I would like to give you some ideas, cause i think your question has something to do with control css overriding.

1. the Jost's LESS or SASS solution is very good actually to prefix cause can use nested css features, but it requires a compile process, their eventually compiled files are still css. cause the .less or .sass files can not be recognized for html to render styling.
2. Another thinking To avoid css conflicts and wrong overriding, 
    Instead of including global styling, see if you can embed them in part of the specific section/page where they can get higher priorities than the rest global styles.
   even the same css, generally, !important > inline css > internal css > external css 
   or javascript can trigger css override after previous css finished rendering on the page.
3. Instead of using css priorities or script running priorities to override styles, making two external mobile.css, destop.css for example, then using javascript to reload page to include different stylesheet when  device width are detected to have been changed in browser resizing behavior.(This is one pop way used in responsive view)
4. using IDE to locate css patterns and replace them with your prefix if it's simple to match all the patterns.